# Preload files into memory and called by other utility as argument

Tags: python, performance, mmap

When I launch one .jar in Python, I will give filename as argument for that execute .jar file.  such as: `java -jar xx.jar -file xx.file`
I just noticed, when that Java process try to read xx.file as i/o read, it will cost 30% CPU usage in task manager.
So I think about, if we can pre-read files to memory, can mmap do that?

Any suggestion to improve it? If I have more than 50 java.exe process, CPU usage and i/o issue should be an big issue for me.

Comment: What do you mean _"...it will cost 30% cpu usage..."_? For how long? Why do you believe this is a problem?

Comment: Your comment about "task manager" hints about windows, but you tagged the question with mmap. I don't think that's a way forward. :)

Answer (score 1):

This does not really seem like a python question at all. But...

If you have 50 processes reading the same file, your OS will most likely cache this file for you already (if there's enough space to cache it of course)

That should remove the problems with I/O (disk) cost. 
But you say that reading results in 30% CPU usage in task manager. Do you know what this CPU time is really used for? Is it for reading the file? JIT-compiling your java code? Just starting up the JVM:s?

You should make sure you know exactly what the problem is before trying to solve it.

Comment: no, i not call the same files, i called different file, but that file is a little small, about 1.44mb, floppy image.

Comment: one more thing, i don't have that java code, i only have binary. in my python code, it will call popen to call like we execute it under command line(java -jar xx.jar -file xx.file), so i want to make sure if we can provide xx.file in memory and allow jar application to read it as argument.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: You start up a JVM to process a floppy-sized file? you really should measure where the performance problem is. It is possible that starting up the JVM takes much more power than processing that file, for example.